# How do proper exception handling in C# while using await inside try which inside foreach loop?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, telegram-bot

Sometimes my messages aren't being broadcasted to channels even if before it was working. I'm afraid it's because of improper calling async methods inside try/catch block inside foreach loop.

What can be the problem and what is the way to solve it?

```
    public void Broadcast(string articleLink, string articleCategory)
    {
        var targetChats = _telegramService.GetTargetChats()
            .Where(chat => chat.FeedCategory == "news" ||
                           chat.FeedCategory == articleCategory);

        InternalBroadcastAsync(articleLink, targetChats);
    }


    private async void InternalBroadcastAsync(string articleLink, IEnumerable<TelegramChannel> targetChats)
    {
        Logger.Info(Tag + $"|InternalBroadcastAsync| Article to broadcast: {articleLink}");

        foreach (var chat in targetChats)
        {
            try
            {
                var broadcastedMessage = await _telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                    chat.ChannelName,
                    articleLink,
                    replyMarkup: CreateReplyMarkup(0, 0),
                    parseMode: ParseMode.Html);

                SaveBroadcastedMessage(broadcastedMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Logger.Warn(Tag + $"|InternalBroadcastAsync| Failed: {exception.Message}");
            }
        }
    }


    private void SaveBroadcastedMessage(Message broadcastedMessage)
    {
        if (broadcastedMessage == null) return;

        var messageToSave = new TelegramMessage
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            MessageId = broadcastedMessage.MessageId,
            ChatId = broadcastedMessage.Chat.Id,
            LikeNumber = 0,
            DislikeNumber = 0
        };

        _telegramService.SaveMessage(messageToSave);
    }
```

Comment: If an exception occurs you log it, do you get log events? Is is enough to *only* log it? Should you retry? Retry if specific exceptions? Your exception handling is fine for logging, but definitely not for *handling* the problem.

Comment: async void... bad mmkay

Comment: async functions should return `Task` instead of `void` and `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResult`. One and only exception: the event handler

Comment: As others have said, `async void` (and async void lambdas) [should be avoided in most everything except top-level event handlers](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only) (so, avoid in lower-level event handlers too).  In `InternalBroadcastAsync`, your method returns to the caller at `SendTextMessageAsync` before completion, and since it's void, the method returns as done.  So, any exception is left dangling, and won't get caught in your catch. That's because its return type is void.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, InternalBroadCastAsync is an async function. Therefore it should return `Task` instead of `void` or `Task<TResult>` instead of `TResult`.

Callers of this function should also be async ans thus return Task. The only exception is the async event handler. This async event handler should return void, indicating that you can't await it.

Every async function should await all other async functions that it calls before returning.

This results in:

```
// the async event handler returns void
private async void OnButtonBroadCast(object sender, ...)
{
    // this is the only function that returns void instead of Task
    await this.BroadCast(...);
}

async Task Broadcast(string articleLink, string articleCategory)
{
    var targetChats = ...
    await InternalBroadcastAsync(articleLink, targetChats);
}

async Task InternalBroadcastAsync(string articleLink, 
    IEnumerable<TelegramChannel> targetChats)
{
    Logger.Info(...);

    foreach (var chat in targetChats)
    {
        try
        {
            var broadcastedMessage = await _telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(...);
            SaveBroadcastedMessage(broadcastedMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you want to continue processing chats when you can't send one of them, but that's your decision.